# How to compare two lists in python using if condition

Tags: python, list

Using python I would need to tackle the below scenario, where we have two lists name_1 is static and name_2 is dynamic. When we compare the two lists if there is any missing or partial value in name_2 then i need to print the name_1 value corresponding to name_2.

2 scenario: If there is extra value in name_2 then i need to print it directly.

```
name_1 = ['mahesh','karthik','python_code','Karun']
name_2 = ['mahesh','karthik','pyth','Karun','mari']

list_match = []

i = 0
while i < len(name_2):
    if not name_2[i]:
        print("Incorrect element founded in position ", name_1[i])
        break
    elif name_2[i] not in name_1:
        print(f"'{name_2[i]}' is extra column in position ", i)
        break
    else:
        list_match.append(i)
    i+=1
```

Expected Output1:

```
Incorrect element founded in position  python_code
```

Expected Output2:

```
'mari' is extra column in position  4
```

Comment: `if not name_2[i]` can never be true.

Comment: so, in order to meet that criteria what way would be used there?

Comment: What is "incorrect"?

Comment: What criteria do you mean?  As written, the if statement will never be true, so you must mean something else.

Comment: if not name_2[i] like you said it never be true. So, in that case what can write in if clause to satisfy the above mentioned condition is my question.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:

```
mismatches = [(i, el) for i, el in enumerate(name_1) if not el in name_2]
for idx, el in mismatches:
    print(f"Incorrect element founded in position {idx}: {el}")
```

Then just reverse it for the other list.

```
mismatches = [(i, el) for i, el in enumerate(name_2) if not el in name_1]
for idx, el in mismatches:
    print(f"Incorrect element founded in position {idx}: {el}")
```

Comment: Can't we do it in a single go just by checking len of two lists. So, that i can pass dynamically which to execute

Comment: A word of warning - this solution is `O(n^2)`, which means it will be very slow on particularly long lists. You could hasten it with some pre-processing (move the lists to sets for the `if not el in` comparison).

Comment: while doing in the above way is not suffice in my case. Could you modify the code which i had been put in there. So, it would be great